# How to check if inside Facebook Canvas

Tags: javascript, facebook

[Facebook application, how to check if inside Facebook canvas / standalone using PHP?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2553442/facebook-application-how-to-check-if-inside-facebook-canvas-standalone-using)

This question is an exact duplicate of above question, but the solution for above methods doesn't seem to work now, any updates? and regarding the HTTP_REFERRER header, i found some problems inside Firefox. Any other hacks?

Answer (score 1):

Being passed a valid `signed_request` might be one way to test this...

Only **your** application with its `APP_SECRET` will be able to decode that `signed_request` so it is un-likely that someone would be able to spoof a valid `signed_request`; If they are able to do that - then they have pretty much bypassed Facebook security.

<sub>If they managed to do that, then *maybe* they *deserve* to be able to use your application outside of Facebook ;)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I just do this ($this <--- is a facebook sdk object):

```
$this->signedRequest = $this->getSignedRequest();
if(!$this->signedRequest){
    show_404();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static function referrerIsFacebookCanvasApp() {
    if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "apps.facebook.com") === false || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "facebook.com/l.php?u=") !== false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Referrer headers can be faked, Lix's answer also verifies the request really came from Facebook